# Redis SCAN not giving all matches in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using a Node.JS script with the `redis` npm package to retrieve all the Redis keys that match a pattern `animals:toFeed:*`. An example of a match will be the key `animals:toFeed:17ed160f59c5b31caf7e741a4e62cb7785414cd`.

Using the code below, there can be 10 matches but the code will only return a few like 2-3. What might be the issue, and how can we fix it?

*Using Redis 4.0.11, Node.js 8.11.3, redis 2.8.0 npm package*

```
async function scanAsync(cursor, pattern, results) {
    return redis.scanAsync(cursor, 'MATCH', pattern, 'COUNT', '10')
        .then(function(reply) {
            cursor = reply[0]
            if(cursor === '0') {
                console.log('Scan complete')
            } else {
                console.log('Match #', i)
                let keys = reply[1]
                keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
                    results.push(key)
                })
                return scanAsync(cursor, pattern, results)
            }
        })
}

let keys = []
let prefix = 'animals:toFeed:*'
await scanAsync('0', prefix, keys)
```

### Update

1. Restarted redis. Still having incomplete SCAN results
2. Deleted all keys that matches the pattern and added some keys back. Now everything is returned when doing the SCAN. After an hour of playing, it starts returning incomplete results once more. Repeating this no longer works to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to add keys into `results` when cursor equals `'0'`, but you should always add those.

You may consider your code as follows:

```
async function scanAsync(cursor, pattern, results) {
    return redis.scanAsync(cursor, 'MATCH', pattern, 'COUNT', '10')
        .then(function(reply) {

            let keys = reply[1]
            keys.forEach(function(key) {
                results.push(key)
            })

            cursor = reply[0]
            if(cursor === '0') {
                console.log('Scan complete')
            } else {
                return scanAsync(cursor, pattern, results)
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the problem of always missing one key. Also changing `'10'` to `'1'` allowed me to consistently get all the missing keys. How do you decide what number to use here? In my current test, there will only be 1 to 6 key matches, but in production this can range from 0 to 1000s key matches

Comment: It entirely depends on your system and preference. Smaller `count` would take many more calls and so longer time to complete a whole scan iteration. On the other hand, larger `count` would complete a whole scan iteration faster but make all other calls to wait longer.

Answer (score 1):

… or you use [redis-async-gen](https://github.com/wspringer/redis-async-gen), which prevents you from having to carefully control all of this yourself. (Read more about it [here](https://dev.to/eastpole/redis-async-generators-3ed).)

```
const redis = require('redis')
const client = redis.createClient(…)
const generators = require('redis-async-gen')
const { keysMatching } = generators.using(client)

const results = []
for await (const key of keysMatching('test*')) {
  results.push(key)
}
```